# Как игнорировать странные utf8 символы но оставлять буквы (иероглифы)?

Tags: javascript, utf-8

Я хотел бы сделать код, сохраняющий арабские/китайские/японские никнеймы, но не дающий сохранить что-то вот такое: ̸̧̤̺͕̮̮͇̱̺̥̭̃̋̐͐̀̏͊̍̒̏͌̉̓̔̕ͅ

Comment: Например, можно написать регулярное выражение, запрещающее вводить что-либо, кроме конкретных символов

Comment: Да, но тогда придётся разобраться в китайском/японском написании, не уверен что задача из лёгких...

Comment: в регулярном выражении можно написать что-то типа `/а-я/`. Просто загуглить первый и последний иероглиф каждого из алфавитом, например, Японского языка и готово

Comment: [Список символов Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) вам в помощь. Выбирайте нужные диапазоны символов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, в вашем примере под запрет попадает группа символов, относящаяся к категории Юникода «Nonspacing Mark». Вы можете исключить её, используя [Unicode property escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes):

```js
let str = 'что-то вот такое: ̸̧̤̺͕̮̮͇̱̺̥̭̃̋̐͐̀̏͊̍̒̏͌̉̓̔̕ͅ';

console.log(str);
console.log(inspectString(str));

str = str.replace(/\p{Nonspacing_Mark}+/gu, '');

console.log(str);
console.log(inspectString(str));

function inspectString(string) {
  return [...str].map(
    ch => [ch, `U+${ch.codePointAt(0).toString(16).padStart(4, '0')}`]);
}
```

Подробнее:

https://2ality.com/2017/07/regexp-unicode-property-escapes.html
https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es-unicode-property-escapes

Но если вы не очень хорошо знаете языки, с которыми предстоит работать, такая огульная чистка может удалить и какие-то полезные символы.

**UPD**

Предлагаю алгоритм разрешения подобных проблем.

1. Находите code point символов при помощи вспомогательной функции из примера ниже.
2. Гуглите это число в шаблоне U+число, переходите на сайт вроде этого: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/12031/index.htm
3. Ищите в описании подходящие свойства символа — общую категорию Юникода, скрипт, бинарное свойство и т.д.
4. Подбираете подходящее регулярное выражение. Возможно, пригодится эта заметка: https://habr.com/ru/post/350448/ (в каких-то детялях может быть уже немного устаревшей).

```js
let str = 'такие  можно';

console.log(str);
console.log(inspectString(str));

str = str.replace(/\p{Script_Extensions=Cuneiform}+/gu, '');

console.log(str);
console.log(inspectString(str));

function inspectString(string) {
  return [...str].map(
    ch => [ch, `U+${ch.codePointAt(0).toString(16).padStart(4, '0')}`]);
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Подскажи пожалуйста, а такие  можно тоже как-то игнорировать?

Comment: Да, я добавил вторую часть ответа.